# Powershell Delete only 1 item in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have 300 files in my document library and I need to delete one of them, I cant use the delete out of box option and I though I can use PowerShell to force it. Can anyone have any idea about this:

this one delete all files in library:

```
$web = get-spweb ""
$doclibsname = ""
$list = $web.lists | where {$_.title -eq $DocLibsname}
$items = $list.items
foreach ($items in $items)
{
$list.getitembyid($item.id).delete()
}
```

Comment: which item you want to delete?

Comment: It's because there is the Foreach instruction. How do you know the file you want to delete? do you have its id, or title name?
If you have one of this element, you can change the line with:
$item = $items.GetItemsById() and $item.Delete().

Comment: You need to add an if statement into your powershell to identify only the item you want to delete by title or some other attribute first.

Comment: No response found from you! :(. did my trick work for you?

Comment: There's a typo in the `foreach`.  Change `($items in $items)` to `($item in $items)`

Answer (score 8):

You have to find your item at first based on a condition. Like

```
If($item.ID -eq 10)
{
$item.delete()
}
```

OR

```
If($item["Some Column Name"] -eq "Some Value")
{
$item.delete()
}
```

If you know the `$item` ID already, then it is very easy to delete

```
$list.getitembyid("ID of your Item").delete()
```

There are other operators you may use in `If` statement like

`-ne` : not equal,

`-gt` : greater than,

`-ge` : greater than or equal to,

`-lt` : less than,

`-le` : less than or equal to,

`-like` wildcard comparison,

`-notlike` : wildcard comparison,

`-match` : regular expression comparison